# Getting Current age by user input javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**I want my user when they click on “view age” button to calculate there age from there input**, but i couldn't figure it out. I got the user to view there birth year when they click on the but.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="birth">
    <h2>What month were you born?</h2><input name="birthMonth" type="text" size="20">
    <h2>What day was you born?</h2><input name="birthday" type="text" size="20">
    <h2>Your birth year?</h2> <input name="birthYear" type="text" size="20">

    </form>
    <button onclick="outputbirth()">Submit</button>
    <button onclick="submitBday()">View Age</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <p id="age"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

JavaScript Code, function submitBday is the button on the html document:

```
    function outputbirth() {
    // Getting the form id "birth"
    var x = document.getElementById("birth");
    var text = "";
    // Getting the users input values of Month, Day, Year.
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    text += x.elements[i].value + " ";  
    }
    // This is going to print out the result on output id in the html document 
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
    }

   function submitBday() {

   }
```

Comment: I copied your code into [a codepen](http://codepen.io/ntdb/pen/BNKwyN?editors=101) and it seems to work just fine! Is your javascript getting included correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already concatenated a string from the input fields. So what you want to do to calculate the age is to construct a date object from the input fields. Just collect the input fields like you did before in a loop, but do not separate the values by an empty space but use a comma.

```
var bDay += x.elements[i].value + ",";
```

Then pass the bDay to a new date object.

```
var start = new Date(bDay);
```

Now subtract the just created date from now.

```
var elapsed =  Date.now() - start;
```

This will give you the age in milliseconds. To calculate the years from milliseconds you could do this.

```
var age = Math.floor(((((elapsed / 1000) / 60) / 60) /24) / 365);
```

This will give you the age in years. If you want to find out more about the JS date object check out the moz dev network page on [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

I left a snipped for you. Have fun.

```js
function submitBday() {
  var now = Date.now(),
      x = document.getElementById("birth"),
      bDay = "",
      start,
      elapsed,
      age;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    bDay += x.elements[i].value + ","; 
  }

  start = new Date(bDay);

  elapsed =  now - start;
  age = Math.floor(((((elapsed / 1000) / 60) / 60) /24) / 365);
  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "You are " + age + " years young.";
}
```

```html
<form id="birth">
  <h2>What month were you born?</h2><input name="birthMonth" type="text" size="20">
  <h2>What day was you born?</h2><input name="birthday" type="text" size="20">
  <h2>Your birth year?</h2> <input name="birthYear" type="text" size="20">
</form>
<button onclick="submitBday()">View Age</button>
<p id="age"></p>
```